# How to effectively compare two sentences and say both are equal

Tags: pattern-recognition

I want to compare two sentences.I want pattern matching techniquies

For example :

```
  The first thing you will do is choose a topic
  Vs
  The first thing you will do is choose a topic
```

Expected result for this is : Patten matched

```
  The first thing  will do is choose a topic
  Vs
  The first thing you will do is choose  topic
```

In this case also patten matched,but with some error.

This is a simple example , i have to match pattern for complex sentences.

I google this and got dot matrices method . Is this the correct one to apply ? Any other method is there to find out whether two sentence matchs with one another .

Comment: @Arthur I flagged it. And it helps those, who don't want to read off-topic questions at this site. It needs a moderator attention anyway, so it can be reopened and then migrated without trouble.

Comment: Might be an appropriate question for [cross validated SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: String kernels within an SVM

Comment: have you find any solution? If then please let me know. I am also in similar situation and needs some help.
ahmedshihab7@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar sort of problem in one of my earlier projects and I solved it by the following algorithm.

```
I applied the "Longest Common Substring" algorithm and founded the longest common substring between the two strings.

Then I used "Levenshtein Distance algorithm" to compare my String A with the "Longest Common Substring" found from step 1.

If the result available from the algorithm mentioned in step 2 is above certain threshold, then it implies that the string A and String B matches.
```

Comment: I want to find out difference between two string . How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have some way to parse out sentences, and that you only care about whether sentences are the same or not rather than *how* they may differ, then you can simply look for string equality. Consider this Ruby method:

```
def sentences_eql? sentence_one, sentence_two
  sentence_one == sentence_two
end
```

When you feed this method a pair of sentences, you get a Boolean result based on the string comparison. For example:

```
sentences_eql? 'The first thing you will do is choose a topic.',
               'The first thing you will do is choose a topic.'
#=> true

sentences_eql? 'The first thing you will do is choose a topic.',
               'The first thing you will do is choose   topic.'
#=> false
```

If you care about the actual details of the differences, you might use [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or create a word-diff using a longest common substring algorithm. As an example of the latter, see the [diff-lcs](https://github.com/halostatue/diff-lcs) gem.